# How to add 2 strings to jQuery .html()

Tags: jquery

I have the following vars:

```
   $delBtn = $('text');
   $updateBtn = $('text2');
```

Now, if I want to insert one inside another element, I would use:

```
  $element.html($delBtn)
```

But how can I inset them as a concatenated pair?

```
 $element.html($delBtn + $updateBtn)
```

Does not appear to work?

Comment: You can use append $element.append($updateBtn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), which'll take as many parameters as you need:

```
$element.append($delBtn, $updateBtn);
```

If you need to empty it first, that's easy to do:

```
$element.empty().append($delBtn, $updateBtn);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either concatenate the HTML as strings:

```
 $element.html($delBtn.html() + $updateBtn.html())
```

**Note:** *This will copy the elements and not move them.*

Or `add` the elements into a single jQuery object/collection to append:

```
 $element.empty().append($delBtn.add($updateBtn));
```

or http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/0bp2h0Lu/

```
 $element.empty().html($delBtn.add($updateBtn));
```

**Note:** *These will move the elements (which is what you specified).*

You are better off using the other methods like `empty()` to clear it and `append()` to add children as that will be faster than re-parsing the HTML and re-creating elements.